# In-memory database and programming language memory management / garbage collection

Tags: java, python, database, in-memory-database

I've been reading about in-memory databases and how they use RAM instead of disk-storage.

I'm trying to understand the pros and cons of building an in-memory database with different programming languages, particularly Java and Python. What would each implementation offer in terms of speed, efficiency, memory management and garbage collection?

I think I could write a program in Python faster, but I'm not sure what additional benefits it would generate.

I would imagine the language with a faster or more efficient memory management / garbage collection algorithm would be a better system to use because that would free up resources for my in-memory database. From my basic understanding I think Java's algorithm might be more efficient that Python's at freeing up memory. Would this be a correct assumption?

Cheers

Comment: Are you asking what would be the better language in which to implement the in-memory database itself, or which language would be better for an application that uses an in-memory DB?

Comment: Depends on your use case totally. Python uses reference counting to free objects as soon as they have no references. This means most of the time everything is cleaned up by reference counting and GC never kicks in. There is also usually no need to tune various GC parameters as in Java.

The disadvantage is that the reference counter incurs extra bookkeeping and locking overhead. But again which one to opt for, depends on your use case.

Comment: I'm more focussed on an application that uses a in memory database, but would be interested in perspectives on which language would be better as well @KevinAnderson.

Comment: Use case for financial institutions @Amitkumar

Answer (score 0):

You choose an in-memory database for performance, right? An in-memory database written in C/C++ and that provides an API for Java and/or Python won't have GC issues. Many (most?) financial systems are sensitive to latency and 'jitter'. GC exacerbates jitter.